# Emberjs computed property in model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, model

I'm trying to use a computed property in a model to render data in the template. Here's a snippet of my model:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {  
    ...
        divStyle: function() {
           return "height:" + this.get('height') + "px; color:"+ this.get('color') +";";
        }.property('height', 'color')
    }
}
```

and here's a snippet of my template:

```
{{#each}} <div {{bindAttr style="divStyle"}}</div> {{/each}}
```

But I'm getting the following error: "Assertion failed: Attributes must be numbers, strings or booleans, not function". I was following this post: [Ember.js binding a css style in a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033728/ember-js-binding-a-css-style-in-a-template) and somehow its not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't define the computed property in the `model` function. You must define computed properties on the controller or the route. [See here for more information about computed properties](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/).

---

But as you are trying to calculate the style within an `each` loop, you need to take a different approach to get the style for each of your items.

I would use an [Ember Handlebars Helper](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/) like this to set the style.

### Helper

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper("getStyle", function(o){
    return "height: " + o.height + "px;" +
           "width: " + o.width + "px;" +
           "background-color: " + o.color; 
});
```

### Usage

```
{{#each}}
    <div style="{{unbound getStyle this}}"></div>
{{/each}}
```

### Demo

You can see a working [JSBin here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OGUZaZaq/1/edit).
This demo uses an each loop and a model containing style information to create this:

[image: Screenshot]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sure, putting the computed property in the controller worked. Thanks! Also, the jsbin is awesome!

Comment: You can also add computed properties to your [model classes](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/).

Answer (score 5):

You either need to define it on the model class, not inside of the model hook, or the controller class associated with the route (`application`).